# Using HTML and CSS from a template in a component in Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, themes

I'm trying to take a HTML theme and convert it into an Angular2 website.

Here's a short example of what I mean:

I write a component with a class name list.

list.component.html

````
```<aside class="list">
   <ul>
      <li>Example</li>
   </ul>
</aside>
```
````

When I try to use this component in another html template like so..

- main.component.html

  `<h1>Main</h1>
  <app-list></app-list>`

The styles do not match exactly what the them looks like in regular HTML.

When I inspect the page, this is what I see.

````
```<div class="content">
    <h1>Main</h1>
    <app-list _ngcontent-iua-7 _nghost-iua-0>
       <aside class="list">
          <ul>
             <li>Example</li>
          </ul>
       </aside>
    </app-list>
</div>```
````

The problem is my theme is wrapped around a content div, in index.html and the styles are like such.

```
.content aside.list{
    //blah blah blah
}
```

Since the component tag is part of the DOM, those styles won't render and the page isn't style correctly at all. Its going to be a lot of tedious work to get this looking correct if I need to make changes. Then I'm sure IE, Firefox and mobile will be negatively affected.

Wonder if anyone knows an easier way

Comment: What is a or the "content div"? What is the problem? What CSS is not applied where?

Comment: Where is your content div?

Comment: Looks like I left it out.. sorry about that, I've added it.

Comment: What does "Since the component tag is part of the DOM, those styles won't render" mean? I still don't get what the problem is.

Comment: css is expecting div.content>aside.list, but page html is div.content>app-list>aside.list